# Trying to create a dynamic form in react, data not being passed into component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to create a dynamic form in react where a dropdown's options are determined by what ever is selected from a previous dropdown.

For context this is a class booking form and a room can only be booked by certain tutors depending on the subject that has been selected, so selecting
'Geography' would populate the tutor dropdown with a list of geography tutors.
I have included the code for the booking form which is a modal. I am passing the options via into a dropdown component that creates a  and generates the options from an array of objects.

The subject selected goes on the redux state and the relevant tutors are then put into a variable and passed into the dropdown component

However, the second dropdown box is not populating with the options. When I console.log it, the right options appear in the console but do not seem to be getting passed to the dropdown.

Please can you advise on where I’m going wrong.

```
  import _ from 'underscore';
  import React from 'react';
  import {render} from "react-dom";
  import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';
  var {connect} = require('react-redux');
  var actions = require('actions');
  import Base from 'Base'
  import TextInput from 'TextInput';
  import Dropdown from 'Dropdown';

  class RoomBookingForm extends Base {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

      onCloseModal = () => {
      this.props.onClose();
    };

    render() {
      //gets the list of tutors
      let tutorOpts = _.where(this.props.tutors, {subject: this.props.subjectSelected})
      return (
        <Modal open={this.props.open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} little>
            <div className="modal-header-left">
              <h5>Create New Class </h5>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-content-container">
              <form>
                <TextInput type="text" name="name" labelText="Class Name"/>
                <Dropdown model="subjectSelected" labelText="subject" options={this.props.subjects}></Dropdown>
                <Dropdown model="tutorSelected" labelText="tutors" options={tutorOpts}></Dropdown> //tutors passed in here
                <button onClick={this.onCloseModal}>Save</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </Modal>
      )
    }
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      tutors: state.tutors,
      subjects: state.subjects,
      subjectSelected: state.form.subjectSelected
    }
  }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoomBookingForm);
```

Comment: If you can provide a codepen/jsfiddle playground with proper dummy data in place, I could give a hand.

Comment: This is probably happening because your component isn't re-rendering.
I would say do a dispatch whenever you select the subject. This will update your redux state and re-render the component.

Comment: What library provide `Dropdown`? Not really possible to say anything for sure without that info. The code implies that `Dropdown` somehow changes the redux store - is that the case?

Comment: Keep track of your information from your various dropdowns in `this.state`. That way React can handle your dynamic content changes.

Comment: Dropdown is a component I made myself, it just takes an array of objects and creates options in a select. What ever option is selected, the value gets put on the redux store.

At work currently but will try doing a dispatch later, if that doesn't work I will put together a jsfiddle of it and post that.